# What is scenario of using Redux in mobile apps?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am producing mobile app using react native, and after days of learning Redux, and react-redux.

I have a big question mark that:

What is the scenario of using Redux in react-native?

I studied many tutorials that told us how wonderful it manage the state, how simply it manage the actions.

**BUT, is it just happening when you only have many components on one page in your app?**

For example, if I have a app with 2 pages, so called Page A and Page B.

Does redux can maintain the state of A, then using at B? **(I am using react-navigation of jumping among pages**)

**If it can do, what is the different of that I stored state to AsyStorage in A, then fetch it back on B?**

Seriously confused.

Just need your discussion about it please, if I get thing wrongly.

THX!

Comment: you can read this https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

written by redux creator

Comment: My understanding is, when you initialize an App, there is a Store. Within the store, we have objects pageA and pageB with initial values . Whenever we make an action, we will have reducers to update pageA and pageB stores to maintain the state in our app. By using react-navigation jumping among pages will not change the store's state. If you refresh your app, everything will be initialized again.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting into your problem statement let us first see why we should use these tools anyway?

For Handling App's Data:
[State](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html) - It handles component's internal data with not much complexity.
[Props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html) - It tosses data back and forth from parent component to children and vice verse.
[Redux](http://redux.js.org/) - It handles data efficiently using action-reducer-store architecture. Great for a complex app with a lot of user's data to handle.

For Data Persistance:
[AsyncStorage](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.46/docs/asyncstorage.html#asyncstorage) - Simple API to save and manage data on device manually.
[Redux Persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) - Built over Redux to store all the Redux State data to device synchronously.

Now getting back to your situation,
If you JUST have TWO screens to manage data back and forth on, it's better to use just state and props. You don't need anything else.
By calling AsyncStorage you are saving data on the device and then receiving it from the other screen. This is not necessary if you don't want your app's data to remain on the device even after closing the app.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: hi, I just use two pages as example, I was confused about what the benefit of redux and origin state.  If the redux only can work on one page app, then whatever how many pages, it is useless.  Thanks for answer.